# Legend displaying the expected number of points per unit area next to density plot

Tags: plotting

I have 2d points and want to show a colored density plot of them. I also want to display a legend showing which point density (number of points per unit area) the colors in the plot represent.

Let's take the following 2d points:

```
SeedRandom[1];
points = Transpose[{RandomReal[2, 100], RandomReal[3, 100]}];
ListPlot[points, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> Full, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image]

I tried to use `SmoothDensityHistogram`:

```
SmoothDensityHistogram[points, 0.1, "PDF", ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic, PlotRange -> Full, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image]

The density plot looks correct, but I would like to see a color legend labeled with the number of points and not with a probability.

What would be the Mathematike-like solution, which is e.g using for the sliding window `DiskMatrix` or somehow different producing the desired result.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The total number of points times the density gives you the number of points per area unit. What we need to do is to multiply the scale in the legend by the number of points, here is one way:

```
npoints = Length[points];
xlim = Sequence @@ MinMax[First /@ points];
ylim = Sequence @@ MinMax[Last /@ points];
skd = SmoothKernelDistribution[points, 0.1];

scaleMax = NMaxValue[{
    PDF[skd, {x, y}],
    Between[x, {xlim}] && Between[y, {ylim}]
    }, {x, y}, Method -> "SimulatedAnnealing"];

SmoothDensityHistogram[
 points, 0.1, "PDF",
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow",
 PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {0, npoints scaleMax}}],
 PlotRange -> Full,
 AspectRatio -> Automatic
 ]
```

[image: Density plot]

Since we have already done most of the work, we might also create the plot directly using `DensityPlot`:

```
DensityPlot[
 PDF[skd, {x, y}], {x, xlim}, {y, ylim},
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow",
 PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {0, npoints scaleMax}}],
 PlotPoints -> 50,
 AspectRatio -> Automatic
 ]
```

Finally, we should note that the density does not actually say how many points there are in a specific region. It will tell us only that according to the distribution, statistically, that is how many points we would typically find there.

```
NIntegrate[
 npoints PDF[skd, {x, y}], Evaluate[{x, xlim}], Evaluate[{y, ylim}],
 Method -> "MonteCarlo"
 ]
```

> `91.0419`

This tells us that statistically the expected number of points inside the plot range, if there are 100 points overall, would be 91. Increasing the plot range a bit will include almost all of them:

```
NIntegrate[
 npoints PDF[skd, {x, y}], {x, -1, 3}, {y, -1, 4},
 Method -> "MonteCarlo"
 ]
```

> `99.905`

---

**Addendum**

Here is a version which corresponds to the self-answer by mrz:

```
SmoothDensityHistogram[
 points, 0.1, "PDF",
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow",
 PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {0, npoints Pi 0.2^2 scaleMax}}],
 PlotRange -> Full, 
 AspectRatio -> Automatic
 ]
```

[image: Density plot 2]

The difference is that instead of showing the expected number of points inside one area unit, we show the expected number of points inside a region of an area corresponding to a circle of radius 0.2.

---

**Addendum 2**

Here is how to use a specified range for the color bar:

```
cf = Function[x, ColorData["Rainbow"][x/80]];

DensityPlot[
 npoints PDF[skd, {x, y}], {x, xlim}, {y, ylim},
 ColorFunction -> cf,
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
 PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{cf, {0, 80}}],
 PlotPoints -> 50,
 AspectRatio -> Automatic
 ]
```

[image: Density plot with fixed color bar range]

In this example, the range goes from 0 to 80. The key points to take note of is that I turned off function scaling with `ColorFunctionScaling -> False` and provided my own custom color function for both the color bar and the density plot.

If I had used `SmoothDensityHistogram` instead of `DensityPlot` then its color function would have to account for the fact that the probability density ranges from 0 to 1 and not 0 to 80, as the number of points in this example.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution. Please excuse me, but I think I do not understand the PDF result: When I look at the red spot at about {0.5,2.4} then the legend shows that there are about 50 points. How can that be if we have only 100 points in total?

Comment: @mrz It represents the density of points at that location, just like the density of water is 1kg/m^3, you have a density of 50 points per unit area at that location. It's the only sensible answer to your question I can think of, it is the only kind of information you will get from a density plot. Be it a density of probability or something else we can never know what happens at a specific point. Points are infinitesimally small. If you have some water then you know that the density is 1kg/m^3 and the weight of the water at (x,y,z) is zero because (x,y,z) has an infinitesimal volume.

Comment: @mrz I've added a version which corresponds to your answer.

Comment: Many thanks for your help.

Comment: I would like to inform you that I tested the number of particles which you display in the legend and it it fits excellent to: `Length@Nearest[points, {x, y},  {All, radius}];
`

Comment: I have a last may be complicated question: 
I obtain such 2d points sets by measuring the positions of moving objects in subsequent digital images (with `IntensityCentroid`) recorded with a certain frame rate.
The found number of objects is temporary varying.
For each point-set I can show with your code the `SmoothDensityHistogram`. Since the number of points varies also the legend numbering varies while the color range is kept constant.
Is it possible to adjust a fixed legend (with fixed minimum and maximum point number)?

Comment: @mrz I wasn't at a computer with Mathematica, so I couldn't answer earlier. I've updated the answer now to address your question.

Comment: @mrz I don't understand, can you give example? (Will not be able to answer for a while. Not at a computer with Mathematica.)

Comment: Now you were faster than I deleted my comment (I had an additional question and thought after some minutes I should not ask endlessly something new). When PlotRange in DensityPlot exceeds the data range of the points then the Frame around is white and I would like to have the same color as for 0 points. I posted a new questions for that, even your example is better. Please see this: https://i.imgur.com/oxyq6wf.png and this follow up question https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/160343/question-about-plotrange-in-densityplot .

Answer (score 1):

This is my old solution, before I found `SmoothDensityHistogram`. It shows the number of points in a circular region (radius=0.2):

```
dx = 0.1; dy = 0.1;
x0 = 0; y0 = 0;
xmax = 2; ymax = 3;
radius = 0.2;

number = Array[0 &, {Round@(xmax/dx), Round@(ymax/dy)}];

Do[
  number[[i, j]] = Length@Nearest[points, {x0 + (i - 1)*dx + dx/2, y0 + (j - 1)*dy + dy/2}, 
  {All, radius}];
  , {i, 1, Round@(xmax/dx), 1}
  , {j, 1, Round@(ymax/dy), 1}
  ];
ListDensityPlot[Transpose@number, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
 AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image]