# Question about PlotRange in DensityPlot

Tags: plotting

I have e.g. the following DensityPlot, where the PlotRange exceeds the internal DataRange:

```
DensityPlot[{-x^2 - y^2, -x^2 - y^2}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic, PlotRange -> {{-1.5, 1.5}, {-1.5, 1.5}}]
```

[image]

How can I fill the white frame around the density plot with the color corresponding to lowest legend value (here -2)? It can be any color scheme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use options `epilog` and `prolog` to combine two Graphics objects:

```
DensityPlot[{-x^2 - y^2, -x^2 - y^2}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotLegends -> Automatic, Frame -> True,
PlotRange -> {{-1.5, 1.5},{-1.5, 1.5}},
Prolog -> {{ColorData["Rainbow"]@0,Rectangle[{-1.4, -1.4}, {1.4, 1.4}]}}]
```

[image: Density plot]

Comment: +1, I like this solution.

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot ... it works also for my last comment in https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/160193/legend-displaying-the-expected-number-of-points-per-unit-area-next-to-density-pl

Answer (score 2):

You can combine two `DensityPlot`s

```
xymin = -2;
Show[DensityPlot[xymin, {x, -1.5, 1.5}, {y, -1.5, 1.5}, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"],
     DensityPlot[-x^2 - y^2, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow",
                 PlotLegends -> Automatic, PlotRange -> {{-1.5, 1.5}, {-1.5, 1.5}}]]
```

[image]