# Can I make the z-axis on the SmoothHistogram3D output show quantity rather than probability?

Tags: graphics, graphics3d, data, visualization, histograms

In `SmoothHistogram3D`, the x- and y-axes are in the form of the original input; 0 maps to 0 and 1 maps to 1, etc. However, the z-axis returns a probability rather than a quantity (or approximate quantity). (I think that's correct, at least.) Is there any way to make the z-axis return the number of points in that area? Maybe the probability times sample size? Thank you!

Comment: maybe you can use `SmoothKernelDistribution[data]` and plot any function of its `PDF`; for example,  `Plot3D[Evaluate[
  Length[data] PDF[SmoothKernelDistribution[data], {x, y}]], {x, -3, 
  3}, {y, -3, 3}]`?

Comment: see this questions: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/160193/legend-displaying-the-expected-number-of-points-per-unit-area-next-to-density-pl and https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/160592/nearest-number-of-neighbors-on-2d-regular-grid

Comment: Have you seen the third argument to `SmoothHistogram3D`? The Details & Options section of the documentation mentions the argument `”Intensity”`.